# Sitecore xdb rebuild index fails at finishing stage

Tags: indexing, xdb-cloud

We are using `solr cloud with zookeeper` for Sitecore 10.2 environment. We have created `xdb` and `xdb_rebuild` collections with aliases `xdb_mainalias` and `xdb_rebuildalias` respectively. When we trigger xdb rebuild, it moves all the way till finishing stage (95%) and fails there. When we dig the logs it says

```
[Error] An error occured during index rebuilding. There will be another attempt to check. The check interval after an error is 00:00:20. 
Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.Failures.SolrRebuildCoreNotFoundException: Collection name for alias: [xdb_rebuild] not found in Zookeeper configuration.
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrCloudRebuildHelper.<LoadCollectionNames>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrCloudRebuildHelper.<SwapCores>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrIndexRebuilder.<CompleteRebuild>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.IndexRebuildFlow.<CompleteRebuild>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.IndexRebuildFlow.<RunRebuild>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.IndexRebuildFlow.RebuildStatusWatcher.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<Start>g__RunRebuildFlowCycle|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Rebuild.TaskExtension.<ExecuteWithInterval>d__0.MoveNext()
```

We have already uploaded configs to zookeeper and created xdb collections using the same. Are we missing anything here?

Comment: Can you confirm you created collections called xdb and xdb_rebuild and these are the references in your connection strings? If so, you may have this backwards as they should be the aliases.

Answer (score 2):

1. Alias should be suffixed with `_internal` and not with `_mainalias`. Make sure your alias are called `xdb_internal` and `xdb_rebuild_internal`. You can use any suffix for sitecore and use the same in the configuration but not for xdb.

   Reference this [link](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/walkthrough--using-solrcloud-for-xconnect-search.html#create-aliases) for more informaion.
2. You must use `xdb` and `xdb_rebuild` in your connection strings, not `xdb_internal` and `xdb_rebuild_internal`. `xdb` and `xdb_rebuild` are the default names of the primary and secondary indexes. If you change the names of the indexes, you must update all connection strings.
3. Also, make sure uniqueKey field has value `id` in xdb schema and not `_uniqueid`. `_uniqueid` is for Sitecore indexes whereas for xdb it should be `id`.

   Example : `<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>`